# Append a dot before each Capital letter and then lowercase the word

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am pretty new in regular expressions therefore I decided to ask for help.

Here is the situation: I have to transform a text from this format [a-z][A-Z][0-9] to this format [a-z][0-9][.] where before each capital letter or alphanumerical character (except when the letter/number is first if the word) should place a dot `.` and then lowercase the entire word.

Here is an example of the replacement pattern:

From this `IAmHuman` to this `i.am.human`

from this `HelloGuys2` to this `hello.guys.2`

from this `isthereany1heRe` to  this `isthereany.1he.re`

I help you get the idea!

Comment: Are you sure of `isthereany.1.he.R.e`? Shouldn't `R` be lower in the result?

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew you are correct. I have edited my original post :)

Comment: Do you have to take care of unicode letters?

Comment: Why the dot before the last `e` in  `isthereany.1.he.r.e`?

Comment: @ enrico.bacis - no needed thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a 2 step approach:

**Find**: `(?<!\S)[[:upper:][:digit:]]`
**Replace**: `\l$0`

where `(?<!\S)` fails the match if there is a non-whitespace before an uppercase letter (`[:upper:]`) or a digit (`[:digit:]`), and then

**Find**: `(?<=\S)[[:upper:][:digit:]]`
**Replace**: `.\l$0`

where `(?<=\S)` requires a non-whitespace before an uppercase letter or digit.

The replacements are different, so we need 2 steps. The `$0` refers to the whole match and `\l` turns the matched character lowercase.

Instead of `[:upper:]` you can use `[A-Z]` and instead of `[:digit:]` a `\d` can be used.

Results:

[image]

Comment: What about the dot? In your comment I saw a second expression  which is not shown here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to modify the 2nd replacement pattern. Updated.

Comment: Very well explained :)